# Proof of Wald's Identity

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I'm looking at the proof of Wald's identity on https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee126/fa17/wald.pdf.

On the last page, under Theorem 2, I follow the proof up to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[E[X_n \mathbb{1}\{N \geq n\}|X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}]]
\end{align}

But I don't understand how the paragraph that follows allows us to write
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E[\mathbb{1}\{N \geq n\} E[X_n |X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}]]
\end{align}

Where the indicator random variable is pulled out of the inner expectation, which is a random variable. I understand that $\mathbb{1}\{X_n \geq n\}$ is independent of $X_n$, and in general, if $A$ and $B$ are independent random variables, then we know $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$ and $E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$, and $E[XY|D] = E[X|D]E[Y|D]$. But in the above, why is $\mathbb{1}\{N \geq n\}$ no longer conditioned on $X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the definition of stopping time, the event $\{N ≤ n-1\}$ is completely determined by $X_1, \cdots , X_{n-1}$, that is $\{N ≤ n-1\}$ can be written as $g(X_1, \cdots , X_n)$.

And for condition expectation, $E[f(X)g\mid X]=f(X)E[g\mid X]$ so you get the next step.

Comment: Where did $E[f(X) g|X] = f(X)E[g|X]$ come from? Not sure if I'm familiar with this property.

Comment: Here [Theorem 1, vi](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf).

Comment: Hmm that's really interesting! I've never seen that before. Thanks for sharing. Also, is there a typo in your answer? Shouldn't the event $N \leq n-1$ be independent of $X_n$?

Comment: Seems I had the wrong premise in my OP. I thought the indicator function was pulled out because of independence, but there was no independence discussion here.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.